# Проверка на дублирование записей в БД

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, oracle

Есть две БД-Oracle и postgresql.
Посредством java в интерфейсе есть кнопка,по нажатию на которую происходит следующее- из Oracle вынимаются данные из одной таблицы и подставляются в сущность,а затем уже в БД postgresql.
Как осуществить запрет на занесение уже вынутых данных при последующей активации?
Это нужно делать на уровне БД или на уровне Java?
Вот пример кода, с некоторыми особенностями, касающиеся исключительно самой системы

```
private static Statement stmt;
private static ResultSet rs;
private static Connection connection;

private void getUsrAndCreateUsr(){
    connection = null;

    String query="select usr_key, usr_status, usr_udf_hrid, usr_last_name, usr_first_name, usr_middle_name, usr_email, usr_udf_hrdateofbirth from usr where usr_status !='Deleted'";

    try{

        connection = getConnect();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()){
            Long usr_key = rs.getLong("usr_key");
            String usr_status = rs.getString("usr_status");
            String usr_udf_hrid = rs.getString("usr_udf_hrid");
            String usr_last_name = rs.getString("usr_last_name");
            String usr_first_name = rs.getString("usr_first_name");
            String usr_middle_name = rs.getString("usr_middle_name");
            String usr_email = rs.getString("usr_email");
            java.sql.Date usr_udf_hrdateofbirth = rs.getDate("usr_udf_hrdateofbirth");
            RUser newUser = new RUser();
            newUser.setStatus(dictContentService.getDictContentByCode(111L, usr_status));
            newUser.setCode(usr_udf_hrid);
            newUser.setLastName(usr_last_name);
            newUser.setFirstName(usr_first_name);
            newUser.setMiddleName(usr_middle_name);
            newUser.setEmail(usr_email);
            newUser.setBirthDate(usr_udf_hrdateofbirth);
            newUser.setDescription("from Oracle");
            newUser.setLocked(false);
            userService.saveBase(newUser);

        }

    }catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try { connection.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: В зависимости от контекста задачи возможно использование уникального индекса.

Comment: допустим, если в Oracle usr_udf_hrid уникальный номер, а у нас получается оно переносится в поле Code

Comment: Индексы можно делать составные. Любое поле или набор полей, которые могут уникально идентефицировать запись назначаются уникальным индексом таблицы в пострегресе и в случае попытки повторной вставки имеющегося индекса будет выброшено исключение.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант запроса для реализации проверки на стороне БД:

```
INSERT INTO usr( usr_key, usr_status, usr_udf_hrid, usr_last_name,
  usr_first_name, usr_middle_name, usr_email, usr_udf_hrdateofbirth ) 
  SELECT <здесь_новые_данные> WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM usr where usr_key=<новый_usr_key> AND <проверка_других_уникальных_полей>
  );
```

На стороне java:

```
SELECT_STRING = "SELECT 1 FROM usr WHERE <проверка_уникальных_полей>";
INSERT_STRING = "INSERT INTO usr(..."

try ( Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ) {

    //check
    boolean isExist = false;
    try( ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery( SELECT_STRING ) ){
        while( result.next() ){
            isExist = true;
            break;
        }
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        throw e;
    }

     if ( !isExist ) {
         statement.executeUpdate( INSERT_STRING );
     } else {
         //statement.executeUpdate( UPDATE_STRING );
     }

} catch( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: не совсем так, получается все равно ориентир идет на БД. Мне кажется это можно сделать посредством проверки на getByCode у сущности RUser.